# Proper use of D.C. al Coda with repeat voltas

Tags: notation, repeats, musescore

I have a score template like this...

[image]

I expect this to be the performance by measure numbers and rehearsal marks...

```
A

     1-8, 1-7, 9

B

     10-25

C 

     26-33, 26-31, 34-38

D.C. al Coda

A

     1-7, 9

B

     10-24

Coda

     39-40
```

This template is in MuseScore 3.6. It plays it once according to the order or measure I expect, but then it plays the whole sequence again but playing only the volta second endings, ignoring the D.C al Coda, and moving from the trio to the coda ending mm. 38-40.

Have I made a mistake with the repeat signs or is MuseScore playing it wrong? I suspect it's my mistake, but I don't know what I've done wrong.

---

EDIT

Screen shots of the inspector, MuseScore 3.6...

[image]

Comment: I made the template. It based on Chopin's short Mazurkas B.16,  1 & 2. Although he didn't use exactly that series of repeats.

Comment: Oops. Meant to vote to close, not actually close. Anyway, see my answer in the duplicate. If that doesn't fix things, send me a comment, and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: ...and if it does work, please feel free to update my answer to reflect that it was verified in MuseScore 3.6.

Comment: @Aaron. The issue isn't playing the repeats for the D.C. I actually don't want that. I tried it anyway, but it still isn't playing right. It gets to the final coda but then starts over again.

Comment: Well, first of all, apparently I can just reopen, so ... done. So the problem is that it ignores the "to coda" after taking the DC repeat, or it never takes the DC repeat to begin with? Obviously, I'm not clearly understanding the problem.

Comment: As with @ElementsinSpace, I created a score that matches yours, and it works fine. MuseScore 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repeat signs are right, it's a MuseScore issue.

Use the *Inspector* on the all the jump signs, and make sure the *Jump* settings are right:

[image: MuseScore with To Coda sign selected - inspector showing jump settings]

---

[image: MuseScore with "DC al Coda" jump sign selected - inspector showing jump settings]

---

[image: MuseScore with Coda sign selected - inspector showing jump settings]

---

#### Update

Here is a link to a copy of the template that I made, and which seems to work as expected:
[Mazurkas - TEMPLATE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijxg5jvof4zdlvz/Mazurkas%20-%20TEMPLATE.mscz?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks for the inspector tip. I added a second screen shot of the inspector settings. It makes sense in terms of what I expect, but MuseScore 3.6 still plays it wrong. I check for updates. It says I'm on the latest.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I made my own copy of the template (not shown), with all the structure in yours (other than the fancy mid-line system break). It seems to work just fine (and without having to adjust the Jump settings), so I'm not sure what's gone wrong.

Comment: I tried taking out the system break between mm. 38, 39 but still plays the same. I'll post over at the MuseScore site, because it seems to be a software issue. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I've added my (working) copy of the template to the bottom of my answer.  However, it doesn't explain why your copy didn't playback properly.  If you can find out what the problem was, that'd probably make a more useful answer.

Comment: I think I figured out the MuseScore issue. Your template worked in my MuseScore. So, I made a brand new page with the same repeats. My new page worked. Then I realized I had imported my original file from an older version of MuseScore and had been editing it. Something about the import from an older version seems to have messed it up. Ugh! Thanks for answering my notation question _and_ troubleshooting MuseScore!